# Async/Await does not work with alert() - javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

i want that the two functions with await keyword executes first then the alert() and location.reload should be executed.

```
 async function CompleteUpload(){
            await LoadValues();
            await UploaderMethod();
            alert("Product Added Successfully!");
            location.reload();
        }
```

***the alert just pops before the 2 await function calls and also the page gets reloaded before these methods are executed.***

```
async function LoadValues(){
        prName = document.getElementById('NAMEbox').value;
        proc = document.getElementById('PROCbox').value;
    }

async function UploaderMethod(){
        var uploadTask = firebase.storage().ref("Laptops/Img" + id+".png").put(files[0]);
            
        uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){
          }, .... //firebase upload data function
```

the upload CompleteUpload() works perfectly if i don't put alert() and reload at the end.

**UPDATED**** (after someone answered about returning a promise)

at the end of upload task i wrote this:

```
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve("yeah");
    }
```

changed the complete upload to:

```
function CompleteUpload(){
            LoadValues();
            UploaderMethod().then(Reeeload());
        }

function Reeeload(){
            alert("Product Added Successfully!");
            location.reload();
        }
```

Comment: I think the problem is, that the `UploaderMethod` returns too early. You probably want to return a Promise and call the resolve method on upload finish. From the part I see, I'd guess it returns after making the upload call, not waiting for the upload to finish

Comment: the upload does not get started before i click ok on the alert method, although it reloaded because i have put it there.

Answer (score 1):

This has absolutely nothing to do with the `alert`.

Your `UploaderMethod` is defined as `async` so it always returns a promise, but that promise resolves before the uploadTask is complete (so it continues to the next statement (the `alert` followed by the `reload`) immediately).

You should:

- Remove the `async` keyword from it (because it isn't `await`ing any promises)
- Return a promise created with the `Promise` constructor
- Resolve that promise inside the `state_changed` event handler (when everything is resolved).

See [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises/43375316).

---

Aside: `LoadValues` does nothing except entirely synchronous DOM accesses. It shouldn't be marked as `async` and you shouldn't `await` the result.

Comment: i updated my question, either i'm returning the promise wrong, or its not working.

Comment: Completely wrong. Either the promise isn't returned from the `UploaderMethod` function or the `resolve` isn't inside the `state_changed` event handler. Take another look at the other question I referenced.

Comment: take a look at this https://codepen.io/TACV/pen/Rwamzaz?editors=0010, its my full UploaderMethod. i have put the promise write after completing the data.set() method and it is within the uploadtask functions.

Comment: Your promise has nothing to do with when state_changed event. Look at the question I referenced for examples.

Comment: ok i have tried my best to understand how promise works https://codepen.io/TACV/pen/Rwamzaz?editors=0010 but now i'm having two problem, (1) same as before alert is still firing first (2) the promise executes as soon as the page loads.

Comment: `UploaderMethod` needs to be a function that returns a promise, not a promise you create immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Is it specifically `alert()` that doesn't work with async/await? What if you replace the `alert()` and `location.reload()` lines with something like `console.log` to see if that executes first as well.

It might be your `LoadValues()` and `UploaderMethod()` causing the problems.

Comment: both alert and then location reload happens, before the two methods, how can they be causing probelm when they run perfectly fine when i remove alert and reload.

Comment: alert and location reload should work fine within an async function so I suspect the issue is with your other two functions - likely `UploaderMethod()`

Comment: `alert` interrupts code execution on the page and reload also cancels code execution. So if your `UploaderMethod` isn't finished yet it will get cancelled. To wait for the method to finish, see Quentin's answer

Comment: Yeah I agree, just meant they should both execute after those other two functions. Quentin's answer should get you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

**await won’t work in the top-level code**

so intead of function(){ } use this ()=>{} and it will work
i made the screenshot from this site. i hade the same trouble (https://javascript.info/async-await)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WL5J.png)